# DD-WRT Iptables Mangle Packets are not marked

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking, router

I have one problem, even in case the rules are applied without any errors, they don't work

Now my configuration

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s 192.168.0.113 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j MARK --set-mark 3
```

Now the table has the following entry

```
MARK       tcp  --  192.168.0.113        0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443  MARK set 0x3
```

Testing the configuration, find out the IP address

```
MacBookCROSP:~ crosp$ ping www.dd-wrt.com 
PING www.dd-wrt.com (83.141.4.210): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 83.141.4.210: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=34.097 ms
```

Make some http requests

**root@CROSP Router:~# cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack | grep "83.141.4.210"**

Got the following

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 106 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53095 dport=80 packets=8 bytes=1185 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53095 packets=9 bytes=8140 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 107 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53097 dport=80 packets=17 bytes=1726 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53097 packets=27 bytes=34596 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 105 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53096 dport=80 packets=18 bytes=1777 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53096 packets=27 bytes=34850 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 3596 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53109 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=220 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53109 packets=1 bytes=60 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 107 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53094 dport=80 packets=8 bytes=1185 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53094 packets=9 bytes=8140 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 116 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53093 dport=80 packets=6 bytes=324 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53093 packets=2 bytes=112 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 116 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53108 dport=80 packets=5 bytes=272 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53108 packets=3 bytes=164 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2 
ipv4     2 tcp      6 116 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.0.113 dst=83.141.4.210 sport=53098 dport=80 packets=6 bytes=324 src=83.141.4.210 dst=193.151.106.238 sport=80 dport=53098 packets=3 bytes=164 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
```

What it wrong with it ? Why packets are not marked ? Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you try to add it to the POSTROUTING chain (also play around with your source IP, remove the ports, etc.), your dd-wrt routes the packages and could reset the marks to 0. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way around.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get PREROUTING to work on DDWRT even thought it worked with vanilla linux kernel. I asked on the DD-WRT forums and I was told to disable the shortcut Forwarding Engine. I believe that this was a qualcomm problem. Ignore the advice about postrouting etc.

The alternative is to use a proxy as the output chain mangling works.